# Rendering XML in Firefox 3.6

Tags: xml, firefox, mime-types

There was a point in time that Firefox (Version 3.5 or 3.6), by default, would render an XML file in a tree like format similar to that which Internet Explorer generates when pointed to an XML file.  Somewhere along the way, Firefox, or my installations of Firefox lost that ability.  Firefox now strips the XML elements from the XML file and displays only a glob of raw text.

It is possible to see the raw XML file using the View Source command.

However, I would like to adjust Firefox so that it will return to a behavior such that XML files are rendered as a 'tree' control with collapsible nodes, etc., much like Internet Explorer does by default for XML files.

I have searched a good bit and there are references to mime type mapping for XML files, or installation of an appropriate XSLT rendering for XML, but I cannot seem to identify precisely what is needed to create this behavior.  Also tried to find a Plug In for this purpose, but nothing that addresses only this particular problem.  No luck so far.

Seems like a really simple issue, but there seems to be frustratingly little information available.

Thanks,

EulerOperator

Comment: This behavior existed since 3.0, if not 2.0. And Firefox retains it in 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox to render the contents of an XML file as a document tree using its default styles, at the very least,

- the file shouldn't link to any XSL stylesheet
- if the file is received from a Web server, the MIME type must be `text/xml` (I think `application/xml` works too, not sure)

  - This is inferred if opening an XML file from disk and the extension is known to Firefox as `text/xml`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your FF profile. Go to Help\Troubleshooting Information and click the button to open the containing folder of your profile.

Backup and then delete the mimeTypes.rdf file, close all instances of Firefox and open Firefox again.

This will force FF to re-generate the default actions for the file types it knows about.